# How can I optimize API calls with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I make the API call for products:

```
Future<void> loadPage(Customer customer) async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    var productList = ProductList();
    var resp = await oauth2Helper.get(
        "https://api.example.com/api/v1/Products?includeHidden=false&includeObsolete=false&pageIndex=1&pageSize=6&includeCount=false&includeOverlooked=false&select=.images%2Cname%2Cid%2Ccode%2CdisplayCode%2CextendedName");
    if (resp.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = jsonDecode(resp.body) as List;
      final productItems = data.map((item) => Product.fromJson(item)).toList();

      // load price
      final futures = productItems.map((product) => product.loadPrice()).toList();
      await Future.wait(futures);

      productList.addAll(productItems);
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) =>
                ProductsPage(productList: productList, customer: customer)),
      );
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load products');
    }
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }
```

within the product's JSON, there is no price, so I need to make a separate call specifying the product ID:

```
class Product {
  bool? wished;
  int? cartRule;
  String? id;
  String? code;
  String? displayCode;
  String? extendedName;
  String? name;
  ProductImage? Image;
  List<VariantImage> variantImages = [];
  Price? price;
  List<VariantProduct> variantProduct = [];
  UnitMeasure? unitMeasure;

  Product(
      {this.wished,
      this.cartRule,
      this.id,
      this.code,
      this.displayCode,
      this.extendedName,
      this.name});

  Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    wished = json['Wished'];
    cartRule = json['CartRule'];
    id = json['Id'];
    code = json['Code'];
    displayCode = json['DisplayCode'];
    extendedName = json['ExtendedName'];
    name = json['Name'];
    if (json['Images'] != null) {
      Image = ProductImage.fromJson(json['Images'][0]);
    }
    if (json['VariantImages'] != null) {
      json['VariantImages'].forEach((v) {
        variantImages.add(new VariantImage.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    unitMeasure = json['UnitMeasure'] != null ? UnitMeasure.fromJson(json['UnitMeasure']) : null;
    loadVariantsProduct();

  }
  Future<void> loadPrice() async {
    var resp = await oauth2Helper.get("https://api.example.com/api/v1/Products/${id}/price?quantity=1");
    if (resp.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = jsonDecode(resp.body);
      price = Price.fromJson(data);
    }else
      print("Error");
  }
```

In this way, the loading of products takes really too much time, like 8-9 seconds.

I tried to search around on YouTube and GitHub, but they all have the product JSON with the price inside, unlike mine.

Comment: Of course this really depends on the API used.

Comment: If I don't call loadPrice inside loadPage, it takes a few milliseconds to load the products

Comment: I think a problem might be that you are waiting for all products to fetch the price. You could simply refresh your UI each time one of products receives the price. Overall duration would be the same, but from the user perspective - something is happening the whole time; they are not waiting for 8-9 seconds for any result to show.